# Codeigniter - Call to a member function result_array() on boolean - Local setup Installation error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I require help in codeigniter as a learner. I am trying to do a local setup but its giving the following error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean in xampp\htdocs\test\application\models\Homemodel.php on line 1144

return $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();

Thank you for help. Stay blessed!!

Comment: Looks like $this->db->get() is returning true or false.

Comment: Thanks!

I am new to coding? can you please let me know the string I tested true and false but its showing the same error..

Comment: Sorry. I don't know code igniter. And I'm not sure why you chose it to learn.

Comment: Switched my website from WP to CI and wanted to learn the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
return $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

with

```
return $this->db->get() ? $this->db->get()->result_array() : [];
```

It names ternary operator, works similar to `if statement`:

```
if ($this->db->get()) {} else {}
```

This error occurs cause of `$this->db->get()` returns a boolean value (true/false)

Comment: @Sum, you're welcome, you can accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has an good documentation

visit : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

**Standard Query With Single Result**

"This method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. **The result is returned as an object**."

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name FROM my_table LIMIT 1');
$row = $query->row();
echo $row->name;
```

**Result Array**
"This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure"

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```